# Can we overide true and false methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, boolean, overriding

Is it possibile to override boolean method like `true` and `false` in Ruby?

For example

```
def true
   rand()
end

def false
   rand()
end

true  #=> 0.7548583661438558
false #=> 0.19239076750079454
```

If I try the above, I get:

```
true  #=> true
false #=> false
```

I'm trying to understand where these `true`, `false` methods are defined.

I know that `&&` and `||` can't be overriden, because `&&` and `||` are short circut operators.

Are `true` and `false` similar? or they are written inside Ruby somewhere?

I'm just experimenting with Ruby.

Comment: `true` and `false` are [keywords](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html), not methods. They cannot be changed.

Comment: You can still call those methods though if you'd like to make things confusing. You just need an explicit receiver e.g. `self.true #=> 0.26251898331474144`  or an implicit receiver if you use a message transmission method  `send(:true)  #=> 0.5491904848256058` or even `method(:false)[]`. But no you cannot override the keywords `true` and `false`

Comment: @Stefan can you post this sentence as an answer? It should then be accepted. As a bonus here the link to the ruby doc https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/keywords_rdoc.html . If you don't want, I can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`true` and `false` cannot be overridden because they are [keywords](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html), not methods. Their values are hard-coded and there's no way to re-assign a different value. (at least not from within Ruby)

Even when implementing a method with the same name, a literal `true` will still resolve to the built-in value.

---

What you can do is change the object, `true` is resolving to for interesting results: (this is just for fun, don't do this in actual code)

```
def true.inspect
  rand.to_s
end

true #=> 0.8499100640573652
true #=> 0.22279583303254913
```

However, the above example doesn't actually change the *value* of `true` in any way. Also, don't think of `true` as a method invocation returning a random float every time it is called. We are looking at the very same object:

```
a = true

a #=> 0.5813338288658235
a #=> 0.6447125630746154
```

What we did is change its *representation* by overriding [`inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#inspect-method), which:

> Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of *obj*.

We see those floats because IRB calls `inspect` in an attempt to print the last expression's result in a readable way.

If we set IRB's output mode to `:to_s`, our change is bypassed and we see `true` again:

```
IRB.CurrentContext.inspect_mode = :to_s

a    #=> true
true #=> true
```